# Is there a C# Bot Builder V4 SDK template for Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: c#, botframework, visual-studio-mac, azure-bot-service

I have been able to find C# Bot Builder V4 SDK templates and tutorials for Visual Studio for **Windows**. However, I can't find the equivalent for the **Mac**. There are V3 templates around for the Mac but I have seen lots of comments that indicate that V4 has breaking security changes, so I don't think that the V3 templates will work. I tried to download the template from Azure, however, it makes assumptions about the location of the `.bot` file. While there is documentation about how to address those in Windows, the process does not work on the Mac.  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` does not add the context menus described in the documentation.

I'd like to edit, build and run locally.

**Update**: Here is how to use **Azure** *Basic Bot* template locally:

To run this bot locally

- Download the bot code from the Build blade in the Azure Portal
- Update the `appsettings.json` file in the root of the bot project with the botFilePath and botFileSecret
- You can find the botFilePath and botFileSecret in the Azure App Service application settings.

Your appsettings.json file should look like this

```
{
    "botFilePath": "<copy value from App settings>",
    "botFileSecret": "<copy value from App settings>"
}
```

**Run in Visual Studio**: Open the .sln file with Visual Studio. Press F5.

**Run in Visual Studio Code**: Open the bot project folder with Visual Studio Code. Bring up a terminal. Type 'dotnet run'.

[Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator](https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator) is a desktop application that allows bot developers to test and debug their bots on localhost or running remotely through a tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no templates for Visual Studio for Mac at this time, but `dotnet` CLI templates are coming soon. If you feel strongly about templates for VS for Mac, [please open an issue on Github so the team can prioritize](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues).

Comment: I assume you can speak authoritatively on behalf of Microsoft. It would have been nice to have included the link. Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone. I'll add the link to the GitHub repo now.

Answer (score 1):

You can find here, How you can use Bot framework template in Visual Studio  Mac

https://www.msdevbuild.com/2019/01/how-to-develop-bot-application-using.html

Comment: That's a broken link

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extensive list of BotBuilder Samples which can be used as a starting point: [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples)

**Update**: Some of the sample code is out of date and will not build properly.